# Default values in KeyValuePairs in Swift

Tags: swift, key-value

Does the KeyValuePairs struct have a similar property to what 'default' does in an enum, i.e. a catch-all value in case a given key is not found? Or is there a way to recreate the same effect without built in  functionality?

I need this to work with some data I'm fetching from an API (and I think I have to rely on KeyValuePairs as this is what Swift's new charts library uses for custom colouring of charts).

Comment: No there is no default and yes it wouldn’t be to hard to add such functionality for a specific use case

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to do that in the context of charts? More specifically, .chartForegroundStyleScale requires that you pass in KeyValuePairs, but it seems really inflexible (e.g. it doesn't seem to accept KeyValuePairs passed in as a var, it only works if you specify the KeyValuePairs inline inside the modifier). Not sure if that's just due to charts still being in beta or if I'm missing something.

Comment: @parmaCod please edit your question and add your code/attempt.